# Recently I changed minimum sdk version to 24 and received 1 lint warning regarding drawable how to fix this?

Tags: android, android-drawable

**Warning says:**
This folder configuration ('v24') is unnecessary; 'minSdkVersion' is 24. Merge all
the resources in this folder into 'drawable-anydpi'.

And when I rename drawable-anydpi-v24 to drawable-anydpi then, it says resource collide with another resource file (png collides with xml). That is there exists a same resource file with .xml extension.

**Please note that in drawable-anydpi-v24 there is png notification icon file.**

And also there is not any folder with name drawable-anydpi. So I renamed drawable-anydpi-v24 to drawable-anydpi.

**My current project has this drawable folders:**
drawable, drawable-anydpi-v24, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-nodpi, drawable-v24, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi

So, in my case, how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: what else did you have in  drawable-anydpi-v24 ?

Comment: Only one png notification image with ic_notification_icon.png name I have in drawable-anydpi-v24.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move your notification icons from `drawable-anydpi-v24` to `drawable` don't create `drawable-anydpi` for this because anydpi takes precedence over other qualifiers and that might be causing you the issue of `png collides with xml`.

And if you already have an XML version of your asset (ic_notification_icon as a vector asset) in drawable then you don't even have to move your png because now vector asset can work in all of the condition because you moved to higher minSDK.

Comment: I need one more help, what I should do with drawable-v24 folder? That folder is empty. Should I delete that?

Comment: now as your min SDK is 24 you can merge the asset to the drawable folder

Comment: drawable-v24 folder is empty. Should I delete that?

Comment: yes, you can delete that because no need for that now

Comment: And I moved that png from drawable-anydpi-v24 to drawable. So now, drawable-anydpi-v24 is also a empty folder. So that can be deleted?

Comment: I also have empty drawable-xxxhdpi folder. Can I delete that also?

Comment: if those are empty then yes you can